# Apache Camel: Route contentof class(bean) to jms

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I have a map like:

`Map<String, MyMessage> map = new HashMap<String, MyMessage>();`

After I do:

```
MyMessage msg = new Message();
msg.setBody("Hello");
map.put("123", msg)
```

It contains String-correlationId and object `MyMessage`
MyMessage contains method

```
class MyMessage { 

   private String someBody;

    String getBody()
    {
        return someBody;
    }

    void setBody(String someBody)
    {
        this.someBody = someBody;
    }
}
```

I need to get object `MyMessage` from map(I can do this) and from Camel invoke `getBody()` to get String of some text from `someBody` and route to jms. 
How can I get content from `MyMessage`with Camel when I will build the route(`RouteBuilder()`) in Camel and send it to jms (second part I know, how to send it to jms)???

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to insert the `MyMessage` object into your Camel route, you can pull out the body like this:

```
 from("direct:myMessageStart").setBody(simple("${body.body}")).to("jms:queue:myQueue");
```

Just to give another example (the above might be confusing because your class method is called `getBody`), if your class looked like this:

```
  class MyMessage { 

     private String message;

     String getMessage()
     {
         return message;
     }

     void setMessage(String message)
     {
         this.message = message;
     }
  }
```

Your route would look like this:

```
  from("direct:myMessageStart").setBody(simple("${body.message}")).to("jms:queue:myQueue");
```

[More information on Camel Simple syntax](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html%20%22Camel%20Simple)

Comment: How can I inset camel object to camel route. Could you give me some example, please.